# Will I have to pay duty for property that I will take back to country of purchase?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, germany, switzerland, taxes

I'm currently studying in Switzerland but in a few months I will return to Germany. After spending half a year in Germany, I'll switch back to Switzerland for a very long stay. Basically:

- 4 months Switzerland
- 5 months Germany
- 5+ years Switzerland

A friend's shop is selling technical devices and they made me an extremely cheap offer for a high-end monitor (ca 900€. Yes this doesn't sound cheap but it's hardware with some tricky medical diagnosis certifications)

If I take this monitor back to Germany with me, it will definitely be above the duty-free limits. But as far as I understand, as a tourist, you don't pay import taxes on personal items that you will take back with you. It seems like the same rules could apply to me.

I appreciate that there are probably many aspects to this problem. Let's assume that this is the only expensive item I'm traveling with. And that I can prove that I will return to stay for a long time. This extremely cheap offer will also be in perfect order. It's not some underhand deal, they'll give me a receipt with VAT etc.

Comment: I don't know what happens when you cross the border by car, but if you take the train to Germany, the chances of customs or border guards searching your luggage and finding the monitor are practically zero. Border police only board very few of the many cross-border trains, and even if they are on the train you're taking, they might at worst want to see your passport (especially if you look "foreign"), but never your luggage.

Comment: The VAT receipt will do no good. A scratch which makes the item non-marketable would help to prove it's a personal item. These are tax and customs-exempt up to CHF 5000. You have to show the pile for inspection. though.

Comment: Since you are not only visiting for a short period as a tourist, but legally speaking changing your country of residence, you are subject to special rules for relocation goods. I would suggest that you ask this question on expatriates.stackexchange.com instead, as I believe it to be off topic here, since it is not about short-term travelling.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on expatriates.stackexchange.com